# Autonomous navigation using navigation stack and hector slam

Tags: slam, navigation, hector-slam, amcl, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to perform autonomous navigation using hector slam and the navigation stack, something similar to this ( [www.youtube.com/watch?v=5V-0Y43i0h8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5V-0Y43i0h8) ) or ( [www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPaa8ZsO0rk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPaa8ZsO0rk) ) .

I have already seen this post ( answers.ros.org/question/59153/how-to-extract-information-from-hector-slam-for-autonomous-navigation/ ) but instead of working with a pre stored map I want the map to be generated using hector_mapping and simultaneously I am able to perform navigation, that to without using the robot's odometry.

I got hector slam working with hokuyo laser and was able to do mapping using just the laser.

So my doubts are:

1. Is it possible to do this without using the robot's odometry and just using the odometry information from the tf that is being published by hector_mapping ( answers.ros.org/question/62081/using-odometry-from-hector_mapping-for-move_base-nav-stack/ ) ?
2. Does AMCL works only with static maps i.e. can AMCL perform localization on the maps being generated in real time ?
3. Moreover do I need AMCL to perform localization in a dynamic map being generated using hector slam ? If, not then how exactly should I make this work without amcl.

I will be happy to provide any relevant info that may be required and I'm sorry for not publishing actual links as my karma is not enough.

Thank you for your time..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73261/autonomous-navigation-using-navigation-stack-and-hector-slam/) by [gautam2410](https://answers.ros.org/users/5500/gautam2410/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2013-08-15

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. yes, you can just forget about your robot's odometry, because hector_slam will provide it.
2. I believe you cannot, for that purpose you would need a slam tool, as gmapping.
3. You do not, you can just do navigation and localization using only hector_slam. Just do not use amcl.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2013-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gautam2410](https://answers.ros.org/users/5500/gautam2410/) on 2013-08-18**:
Thank you for your answer...just wanted to confirm if I should exclude the odom frame while setting the frames for this?

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2013-08-18**:
you should exclude the odometry frame created by your robot, and use the one provided by hector_slam. you need to make sure the name of the frames match the one expected by other nodes.

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-19**:
Did you get it working?

**Comment by [GuillaumeHauss](https://answers.ros.org/users/29510/guillaumehauss/) on 2017-04-18**:
I would be really happy to discuss your implementation with you, as I'm facing the same challenge right now

**Comment by [KennyxD](https://answers.ros.org/users/61254/kennyxd/) on 2020-11-05**:
HI! I have been going around the ROS Answers forum trying to figure out how to have my robot car autonomously drive using hector slam. I was wondering if any of you have accomplished this already?
Thanks!